# How to get browsers to honor the aspect ratio from width and height html attributes with applied css?

Tags: html, css, image

I am looking for a way to reserve space for images in my layout, before they have been loaded.
I am doing this by adding `width` and `height` properties to my `img`.

This works as expected:

```css
img {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
}
```

```html
<img src="" width="300" height="400" alt="">
```

But in my css I want to constrain my image with a `max-width`.
In order to preserve the aspect ratio of the image, I need to set `height: auto`. But if I do that the image's height collapses:

```css
img {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="" width="300" height="400" alt="">
```

Is there any way that forces browsers to honor the aspect ration, that can be calculated from my html attributes?

---

This still seems to be a problem. [Firefox and Chrome are supporting internal mapping of width and height to aspect ratio now](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_aspect-ratio_internal-value) now. This does exactly what I need.

One implementation detail I have noticed though: `src` has to be set on the image for it to work. The example I’ve provided seems to mark the image as being fully loaded and ignores the aspect ratio again.

So for a lazy-load approach we need to add a placeholder image to `src`, which has the correct aspect ratio for it to work.

Even though that solution works for chrome and firefox at the moment, I am still looking for a solution that also supports older browsers and safari. (no need for IE though)

Comment: but you will loss the ratio if you want to honor the attribute

Comment: sorry, maybe that was a bad choice of words. I want the browser to derive the aspect ratio from the attributes and honor that. The browser would calculate an aspect ration of 3/4, which means if `max-height` is set to `200px` the calculated height of the image should be ~`266.7px`.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can solve this with a bit of hackery I'm none too proud of.

Basically, wrap the image in an element to which you set a height calculated from the max-width of your image and the aspect ratio of the image from your attributes.

A few caveats:

- This sets the `height`, not the `max-height` due to the fact that an image with no `src` set has no intrinsic height, despite the attribute.
- If the values of the `height` or `width` attributes, or the value of the `max-width` property in the CSS change, the setting of the `style`'s `height` property would also have to change. A lot to remember to change, depending on how many images you have.

You could solve this all with JavaScript, but since you do not have that tag on the question, I wanted to respect that and give you a CSS-only solution.

I have added a little JavaScript that waits 2 seconds, then sets the source of the image to a dummy image of the dimensions provided to show a lack of distortion and simulate a slow-loading image.

```js
setTimeout(() => document.querySelector('img').src = "https://dummyimage.com/300x400/000/fff.png", 2000);
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img" style="height: calc((400/300)*200px)">
<img src="" width="300" height="400" alt="">
</div>
```